# Recursively copy all files with MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, xbuild

I have the following set of files with MSBuild:

```
<ScriptFiles Include="Server/scripts/**/*.js" />
```

I then copy all of it over to another directory:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(ScriptFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(ScriptFiles->'$(BuildDir)/WWW/scripts/%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

However, what I want to do is copy `*.js`, and copy `/yui/*.*`.  What I tried doing is:

```
<ScriptFiles Include="Server/scripts/**/*.js;Server/scripts/yui/**/*" />
```

However, what this does is flatten the `/yui/` directory and put all of yui's files directly into `/WWW/scripts`.

Is there a better way to do this?

BTW, I'm actually using `XBuild` and not `MSBuild`, but from what I've seen the two are for the most part compatible.

Comment: Where do you expect the files under `/yui/` to go? under `/WWW/scripts/yui/`?

Comment: Yup!  The only difference is I want to include `*.*` for the YUI files, since that directory contains stuff like `.css` files and images and what not..

Comment: Shouldn't that be two separate lines: <ScriptFiles Include="Server/scripts/**/*.js" /> <ScriptFiles Include="Server/scripts/yui/**/*" />

Comment: Yea, I can use two separate lines but won't that copy all the files twice?  The YUI directory is very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Ritch's comment (I added Exclude to avoid copying the same files twice):

Shouldn't that be two separate lines:

```
<ScriptFiles Include="Server/scripts/**/*.js" Exclude="Server/scripts/yui/**/*"/> 
<YuiFiles Include="Server/scripts/yui/**/*" />
```

OR

```
<YuiFiles Include="Server/scripts/yui/**/*" />
<ScriptFiles Include="Server/scripts/**/*.js" Exclude="@(YuiFiles)"/> 

<Copy SourceFiles="@(YuiFiles)" DestinationFiles="..." />    
<Copy SourceFiles="@(ScriptFiles)" DestinationFiles="..." />
```

Answer (score 3):

%(RecursiveDir) would match the wildcard part. So, if under /yui/ you had :

yui/foo/bar/abc.dll

Then, `yui/**/*` would give %(RecursiveDir) as "foo/bar". Is that what you are expecting? If it is, then this should work with xbuild. Which version are you using? (xbuild --help).

"**" is used when you want to collect files from subdirectories also. If what you are trying to do is different, then could you please given an example with few files?

Try something like this:

```
<Message Text="ScriptFile: %(ScriptFile.Identity) , RD: %(ScriptFile.RecursiveDir)"/>
<Message Text="Paths: @(ScriptFiles->'$(BuildDir)/WWW/scripts/%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
```

This should give insight into why it is not working.

Comment: Yea, I already knew why it wasn't working.  I was wondering how to fix it.  It seems using two lines is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, then use two lines and for the 'yui' task invocation set SkipUnchangedFiles=true for the Copy task.

Comment: Sounds good!  I'll either do that or specify all the various extensions that YUI includes in its source.

Comment: @Mike You could filter your `ScriptFiles` collection using the [RemoveDuplicates Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164300.aspx) before copying.

Comment: @Mike Oups - it looks like RemoveDuplicates also removes all RecursiveDir information :-(

Comment: @Filburt - That's no good!  I'll mess around with it more when I get home and see if I can find an efficient solution.