# MSBuild cannot recursively copy files with Copy task

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I'm aware that this type question has been asked before ([Recursively copy all files with MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569222/recursively-copy-all-files-with-msbuild) and [MSBuild recursive copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806518/msbuild-recursive-copy)) however I can't seem to get it to work for my project file.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, so I don't know if anything has changes from all the other information out there. I've also tried following the second example on this page, all with the same outcome: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx

I'm trying to recursively copy files from my source directory to my inetpub directory. I've got the following setup inside my "BuildLocal" target.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <CopyFiles Include="**\*.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(CopyFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(CopyFiles->'$(DeploymentFolder)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" ContinueOnError="true" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

The `DeploymentFolder` variable is setup in my PropertyGroup like so: `<DeploymentFolder>C:\inetpub\websites\TestSite</DeploymentFolder>`

The error message I'm getting is:

```
warning MSB3021: Unable to copy file "**\*.cshtml" to "C:\inetpub\websites\TestSite\**\*.cshtml". Illegal characters in path.
```

Changing the CopyFile Include to be `include="$(ProjectDir)**\*.cshtml"` has no effect either...

Any help on this issue would awesome :)

Comment: Have you tried specifying the source files relative to a directory instead of relying on current working directory which is nearly always a bad idea? Something like `<CopyFiles Include="$(MyProjectDir)\**\*.cshtml" />`

Comment: I've tried the following: `<CopyFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)**\*.cshtml" />` however that only results in the full path in the error message. `warning MSB3021: Unable to copy file "E:\Development\TestSite\src\TestSite.UI\**\*.cshtml" to "C:\inetpub\websites\Test\**\*.cshtml". Illegal characters in path.` It's like the ** is not being expanded for some reason.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it (in fact I've used this way of copying many times) but I don't have VS2015 here. It is indeed very strange there is no expansion. The code shown here is an exact copy of what you are using, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact markup from the .csproj file copied in. There isn't some target or anything I need to reference to make use of the copy command? I'm considering just using something like xcopy in a post build action to get this working :(

Comment: No you don't have to import anything special, the Copy task is builtin. Tried today and can't reproduce it with VS2015 either so something on your end might be broken. Hard to tell what though.. Can you use Copy all together without any wildcards? Is your file proper UTF-8 or ASCII or so? Can you use Copy with just one wildcard instead of recursive? Or maybe first try with just DestinationFolder instead of DestinationFiles, etc.

Comment: The error you're getting indicates that the problem is with the definition of the item, not the `Copy` task.  Does the behavior change if you move the `<ItemGroup>` outside of the `<Target>` that it's currently in?  That forces evaluation of the wildcard to happen before any of the build has occurred.

Comment: I have the same issue. The copy works without recursive path (**). When the publish is from Visual Studio it works, but it doesn't using the command line. Were you able to solve the problem or you moved to some other solution?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there was a file under the project directory with a full path longer than 260 characters (`MAX_PATH`). In that case, you would hit [an MSBuild bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/406) that causes the wildcard to be included as a literal string rather than as the list of files. This is often seen with `node_modules` folders.

As of Visual Studio 2017 (technically with its Preview 5 prerelease), adding an `Exclude` attribute for the folder that contains long paths will get the rest of the files instead of the literal `**\*.cshtml`.

To work around this, you can use an `Exec` task to invoke `robocopy` or similar.